# How to modify generated template to define properties differently

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, t4

How to change VB.NET T4 template under Entity Framework 6 so that instead it generating a property

```
Public Property name As String
```

It would generate

```
Public Property name As String
    Get
        Return _name 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        [Set](_name , value, "name")
    End Set
End Property
Private _name As String
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if things are changed inEF 6 as I have started using Code first approach.

What you can do is if it is EF will generate partial class for you, you can extend the same and define your own getter and setter.

But why would you like to do it as in your case set and get is public?

What benefit are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to make all autogenerated properties to notify of their value changes with minimal manual work. I don't use viewmodels here so I need INotifyPropertyChanged directly into model classes. I can define additional properties in the partial class like that but I need it here to autogenerated ones that T4 creates.